# How to include last word of file in count

Tags: c

I wrote this simple program that will count the length of each word in a file:

```
length = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    ++ length;
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
        -- length;
        printf("length of last word: %d\n", length);
        length = 0;
    }
}
```

Now it does exactly that until it reaches the last word.
I understand why it does so as it will only count a word upon reaching some form of white space while there is not any white space after the last word.
So I'm wondering what would be a way to have this piece of code include the last word in the file?

Comment: Have you considered counting words until you reach `EOF`, and then print the count?

Comment: maybe you should loop forever and then treat eof as a while space (and also break out of the loop).

Comment: What happens if you have a trailing blank on a line?  Or spaces at the start of a line?  I think you need to be more rigorous about detecting when you transition between 'in word' and 'out of word' and how you do your counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to print the length of the last word after the loop is done.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    ++ length;
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
        -- length;
        printf("length of last word: %d\n", length);
        length = 0;
    }
}
if (length > 0) {
    printf("length of last word: %d\n", length);
}
```

Another way is to change your loop condition and break out of the loop after printing.

```
while (1){
    ++ length;
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == EOF){
        -- length;
        printf("length of last word: %d\n", length);
        length = 0;
    }
    if (c == EOF) {
        break;
    }
}
```

BTW, instead of incrementing `length` and then decrementing it in the `if` block, would simply move the increment into an `else` block. Or just print `length-1`.

And it's not idiomatic to put a space between `++/--` and the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In your opinion which one of these two solutions would be the most C like, or would you rate them both equally? I'm trying to develop good form.

Comment: @mauritsc: In context, another option is `do { c = getchar(); if (isspace(c) || c == EOF) { printf("length of last word: %d\n", length - 1); length = 0; } } while (c != EOF);` which is probably most C-like.  Note that you'll be told that the last word is of length zero if given an empty file; that would happen with the `while (1)` loop too.  The first code avoids that — it has its own merits, therefore.  There are lots of tweaks available, based on the ideas shown by Barmar and in this comment.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I do like the approach you suggest here as it seems more concise. I'll be sure to try it out.